# Geometry problem with trisecting lines and angle bisector theorem

Tags: geometry

> In a triangle $ABC, D$ and $E$ lie on $BC$ such that $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{AE}$  trisect. $\angle A,$ and $D$ is closer to $B$ than $E$ is. Furthermore, $AD = 12, DE = 4$ and $CE = 5$. Find $AB$.

From angle bisector theorem we have

$$\frac{AC}{AD} = \frac{5}{4} \Rightarrow AC =15.$$

Also we can find $AE$ pretty easily
$$AE = \sqrt{12^2 + 4^2} = 4\sqrt{10}.$$

From here on I’m a bit stuck, initially I was about to use the angle bisector theorem again for $\triangle AEB$, but I would need to have $DB$ also. How should I continue?

Here is a rough sketch of the situation so that the reader won’t have to start drawing:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think $\angle ADE$ is a right angle?

Comment: Since $\triangle ADC$ is a $9-12-15$?

Comment: So that means $\triangle ABE$ is isosceles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since $\angle ADE=90$, therefore $AD$ is the altitude of $ABC$ and is trisector. Therefore the triangle $ABE$ is isosceles, i.e. $AE=AB=4\sqrt{10}$.